# Writing a pre-commit hook using SharpSvn. Does it lack svnlook propget?

Tags: svn, hook, sharpsvn, pre-commit

I am rewriting an older subversion precommit hook. In our company, we need to make sure that binary files are allowed on commit only if they have the property svn:needs-lock set before commit.

I started writing the hook and it looks like every part of the hook works, but I cannot find how to read, if the property is set.

I would assume, that SvnLookClient would have the SvnLookClient.GetProperty method, but the only one, that I see is SvnLookClient.GetRevisionProperty. Unfortunately GetRevisionProperty doesn't allow to pass the file in question. What am I missing here?

After all, svnlook propget does allow to pass a repository, a transaction, a propertyname AND the path in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [SharpSvn users mailinglist thread](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&dsMessageId=323605).

The function was added to Subversion trunk tuesday and backported to 1.500x yesterday.

Comment: Seems not to work for newly added files (throwing an exception `SharpSvn.SvnFileSystemException: File not found: 
transaction '3-o', path '/demo/wrong.cs'`). It seems that the current property in the repository is returned and not the property of the current transaction. Doing the same thing with the svnlookclient works. Maybe a bug?